# Javascript Sum decimal

Tags: javascript

I wonder why this sum gives me a result that does not make sense…

```
let x = [
  1650,
  1406.25,
  1342.5,
  1421.25,
  1575,
  1350,
  1612.5,
  1100,
  775,
  1275,
  268.8,
  191.4,
  215.4,
  250,
  250,
  250,
  250,
  250,
  250,
  250
];
console.log(x.reduce((memo, amountDue) => memo + amountDue, 0));
```

I am getting `15933.099999999999`

- where is the `0.099999999999` cominng from?

Comment: The values 208.8, 191.4, and 215.4 cannot be represented exactly in binary.  They are infinitely repeating fractions, like 1/3 in decimal.  Thus, you get an approximation.  1406.25 CAN be represented exactly, but those other three result in round-off errors.